# How to Calculate Google Page Speed API Score

Tags: google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am using google page speed api, I am getting response from ['lighthouseResult']['categories']['performance']['score'] and i was gettings 0.92, but this was not right, it shows really good, but if i go to google page speed tool then it shows approx 62. So, I getting wrong response or is there any another way to calculate response score.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are viewing results for desktop (default), you may want to check mobile metrics.

You can switch from desktop to mobile with the `strategy` param: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v4/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#strategy